# Select distinct on each of many column

Tags: sql, hadoop, impala

I am looking for any input on how do I get distinct on every column and process it accordingly. 
I have a table Z with data as below:

```
CNUM    col1    col2    col3
A1        No     124    30
A1        No     125    31
A2        Yes    123    21
A2         No    123    22
```

I need to process this data to load into another table with a single row with rule that if col1 to col3 has more than one distinct value, it is carried forward as NULL. 
The result set should look like this:

```
CNUM    col1    col2    col3
A1       No     NULL    NULL
A2       NULL   123     NULL
```

I started to do this by my sql below:

```
Select distinct CNUM,
Case when qty<>1 then null
else col1 END as col1,
Case when qty<>1 then null
else col2 END as col2,
Case when qty<>1 then null
 else col3 END as col3
From Table1
Left join (
  Select distinct CNUM ,qty from 
        (select CNUM, count(*) as qty
         FROM Table 1 
         Group by CNUM
         having count(*) >1
         )p
    )p1
 on p1.CNUM=Table1.CNUM
```

But the above query gives me result as below which is not what I need.

```
CNUM    col1    col2    col3
 A1       NULL   NULL    NULL
 A2       NULL   NULL     NULL
```

A1, Col1 and A2,Col2 should have values and not null. 
Any idea on what am I doing wrong.

Thanks

Comment: Please provide desired results and a tag for the database you are using.

Comment: Read this.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

I've rewritten the whole query, please try this:

```
select
  q1.cnum,
  case when col1_distincts>1 then null else col1_val end col1,
  case when col2_distincts>1 then null else col2_val end col2,
  case when col3_distincts>1 then null else col3_val end col3
from (
    select cnum
    from Table1
    group by cnum
  ) q1
  join (
    select c1.cnum,
      c1.col1_distincts, c1.col1_val,
      c2.col2_distincts, c2.col2_val,
      c3.col3_distincts, c3.col3_val
    from (
        select cnum, count(*) col1_distincts, max(col1) col1_val
        from (
          select cnum, col1
          from Table1
          group by cnum, col1
        ) group by cnum
      ) c1
      join (
        select cnum, count(*) col2_distincts, max(col2) col2_val
        from (
          select cnum, col2
          from Table1
          group by cnum, col2
        ) group by cnum
      ) c2 on c1.cnum=c2.cnum
      join (
        select cnum, count(*) col3_distincts, max(col3) col3_val
        from (
          select cnum, col3
          from Table1
          group by cnum, col3
        ) group by cnum
      ) c3 on c1.cnum=c3.cnum
  ) q2 on q1.cnum=q2.cnum
```

---

1st try:

I made some changes in your `p1` subquery, like so:

```
Select distinct Table1.CNUM,
  Case when qty1<>1 then null
    else col1 END as col1,
  Case when qty2<>1 then null
    else col2 END as col2,
  Case when qty3<>1 then null
    else col3 END as col3
From Table1
  Left join (
     select CNUM, count(distinct col1) as qty1,
       count(distinct col2) as qty2,
       count(distinct col3) as qty3
     FROM Table1 
     Group by CNUM
 ) p1
 on p1.CNUM=Table1.CNUM
```

And I also considered the distinct counts per columns.

Your original subquery only check for more than 1 records per `CNUM`.

Comment: Thanks Junjie, I tried it. I get error mesage that                                                                                         
    "all DISTINCT aggregate functions need to have the same set of 
    parameters as count(DISTINCT". Impala does not support multiple count distinct expressions.

Comment: I overlooked the Impala tag.. I'll try to adapt on the database and edit my answer later.

Comment: @Pallavi I've rewritten the whole query by not using `distinct` all together. I hope this would work.